# Caesars cipher - Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value

Tags: c, arrays, string, valgrind, caesar-cipher

i have a problem with my school project. Project is about Caesar's cipher, the program input includes message length, encrypted message, and poorly intercepted message (several characters are correct). The output of the program is a decrypted message. The program decrypts correctly, but there is an error in the output of Valgrind. Furthermore, I think I have poorly treated input data conditions.

There is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* One character rotation */
char rotate(char original, int offset){
  char * alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  if (original >= 'A' && original <= 'Z') {
    return alpha[(original - 'A' + offset) % 52];
  }
  else{
    return alpha[(original - 'a' + 26  + offset) % 52];
  }
}

/* String decoding */
void shift(const char *src, char *dst, int offset){
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(src); i++) {
    dst[i] = rotate(src[i], offset);
  }
}

void printResult(char * coded, char * tapped, int size) {
  char decoded[size];
  int matchingLetters = 0, max = 0, recording = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 52; i++) {
    shift(coded, decoded, i);

    // Zjisteni poctu matchingLetters pismen
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++ ) {
      if(tapped[j] == decoded[j])
        matchingLetters++;
    }
    if(matchingLetters >= max){
      recording = i;
      max = matchingLetters;
    }
    matchingLetters = 0;
  }
  shift(coded, decoded, recording);
  printf("%s\n",decoded);
}

/* The main program */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int size;

  if (scanf("%d\n", &size) != 1) {
    printf("Error: bad input!\n");
    return 100;
  }

  char coded[size + 1];
  char tapped[size + 1];

  if (scanf("%[a-zA-Z]\n", coded) != 1 || scanf("%[a-zA-Z]\n", tapped) != 1) {
    printf("Error: bad input!\n");
    return 100;
  }

  if (strlen(coded) != size || strlen(tapped) != size) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: bad input length!");
    return 101;
  }

  printResult(coded, tapped, size);

  return 0;
}
```

Valgrind output:

```
==866== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==866== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==866== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==866== Command: src/main
==866== 
==866== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==866==    at 0x4C2EDB8: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:454)
==866==    by 0x4EA0FA1: puts (ioputs.c:35)
==866==    by 0x400B1D: printResult (main.c:50)
==866==    by 0x400BE7: main (main.c:76)
==866== 
==866== 
==866== HEAP SUMMARY:
==866==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==866==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 8,192 bytes allocated
==866== 
==866== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==866== 
==866== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==866== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==866== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: You could force to uppercase by clearing bit `0x20`, then OR back in the lower-case bit.  Then you don't need a branch and your table can be half the size.  And of course you don't need a lookup at all, just `-'A'`, add, modulo, `+'A'`.  You're basically using a lookup table to implement `+'A'`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Shift does not terminate *dst* (*decoded*), which could cause *strlen* to go into other memory.
2. *Decoded* isn't large enough to contain the string terminator.

As a style note:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(src); i++)
```

is like nails on a chalkboard for many C programmers. It doesn't matter if the compiler might clean it up.